# How to pass error object to socket.io callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using callbacks with socket.io

Client code :

```
socket.emit('someEvent', {data:1}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(err.message); 
});
```

Server code :

```
socket.on('someEvent', function(data, callback) {
    callback(new Error('testing error'));
});
```

With the above code the client side always prints out `undefined`. If I change the server side code to the following I can see the error message.

```
socket.on('someEvent', function(data, callback) {
    callback({message:'testing error'});
});
```

I can pass my own custom objects to the client just fine, just not the error object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`socket.io` data is serialized as `JSON`, which can only represent plain objects. You will need to serialize any errors into a recognizable plain-object format, or let Socket.IO's standard serialization do its thing (which will result in a plain empty object for `Error` instances.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *or let the browser's standard serialization do its thing*?

Comment: @GoloRoden Sorry, just meant define a serialization format manually or let socket.io serialize as `JSON.stringify(new Error()) === '{}')` which is useless.

Comment: What the actual f-word? In this article (http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/) the creator of Socket.io himself goes on about how you should always pass error objects about rather than just plain strings or the such, and then once again here in the Socket.io docs he mentions using an error object in a callback (http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace) but then in reality just converts them to empty objects? I'm baffled!

Comment: Baffled as well. I find (like a number of node projects) that the socket.io doco is a bit light. I've had to resort to reading the source code and writing test rigs to understand some aspects of it.

Answer (score 1):

I also think it's odd that Socket.IO doesn't seem to provide explicit built in support for passing Error objects in a meaningful way.

If you want to have Error objects seralized correctly in Socket.IO callbacks you can define a method like this to specify how serialization with `.toJSON` for Error messages should be handled:

```
if (!('toJSON' in Error.prototype)) {
    Object.defineProperty(Error.prototype, 'toJSON', {
    value: function () {
      let result = {}
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).forEach((key) => {
        if (key === 'stack') return
        result[key] = this[key];
      }, this)
      return result
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  })
}
```

If you are throwing messages from the server you will want to define this on the server, and if throwing errors from a client to the server you will need to define it on the client too.

Note: In this example it strips the 'stack' property when returning errors to the client (to avoid exposing internals to a client), but this may be something worth leaving in, at least for development mode.

## Update: This is a lot easier with ES6

Adapted from a blog post I wrote recently on this:

https://medium.com/@iaincollins/error-handling-in-javascript-a6172ccdf9af

I'm happy to say this easier/cleaner with ES6.

If you define your class extending Error like this:

```js
class ValidationError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message)
    this.name = 'ValidationError'
    this.message = message
  }

  toJSON() {
    return {
      error: {
        name: this.name,
        message: this.message,
        stacktrace: this.stack
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of this being the object that gets passed back:

```js
{ name: 'ValidationError' }
```

It now looks something like this:

```js
{ 
  error: {
    name: 'ValidationError',
    message: 'A validation error',
    stacktrace: '…'
  }
}
```

You can see what to expect by doing this:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(new ValidationError('A validation error'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little router function that works with plain error objects. You might want to remove the stack variable if you're shy.

```
socket.on('api', async (method, args, callback) {
  try {
    const result = await api[method](...args)
    callback(null, result)
  } catch (error) {
    const { name, message, stack } = error
    callback(error.toJSON ? error : { name, message, stack })
  }
})
```