# Adding a timeout for a callback within a promise and rejecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, bluebird

I'm converting socket.io's emit function to a promise like this.

```
var io = require("socket.io-client")
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var _ = require("underscore")

io.emitAsync = function(event, payload){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return io.emit(event, payload, function(){
      var args = _.toArray(arguments)
      if(args[0]) reject(new Error(args[0]))
      resolve.apply(null, args)
    })
  })
}
```

I couldn't use `promiseify` because the `io.emit` callback doesn't return a node-style callback signature. [The first argument can't be an error object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20916142/340688) So the plan is to pass a string error message, the promise above will reject if the first argument is `truthy`. This is all fine and dandy, here's the problem.

If you don't return a `callback` in your `socket.on` then this promise above will never `resolve` or `reject` anything. So what I need is a timeout this `callback`, if nothing comes back within an allotted period of time then it will `reject(new Error("timeout"))`. Thing is I have no clue how to do that. Ideally I can set the `seconds` to wait within the function above, or if know there's no callback for a given event I'd want to `resolve`, so ideally it's a parameter of `emitAsync` itself. Thoughts?

Comment: Uh, node-style callbacks don't insist on the first argument being an `Error` instance? `promisify` should work well here, rejecting when the first argument is truthy.

Comment: @Bergi Good to know! but still doesn't help with rejecting when there's a no callback for an allotted period of time.

Comment: Also notice that `resolve` takes only a single argument, so not sure what you're doing with this `apply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the [Bluebird `timeout` method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#timeoutint-ms--string-message---promise) of course…

The lower-level solution would be to use `setTimeout`:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  io.emit(event, payload, function(err){
    if(err) reject(new Error(err))
    resolve(_.toArray(arguments).slice(1));
  })
  setTimeout(function(){
    reject(new Error("timeout"));
  }, seconds*1000);
})
```