# Socket.io emit empty object if it's an Error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I emit an object of the `Error` class this one arrives empty on the client-side. How can I send an `Error` object through socket.io ??

**Example:**

```js
let error = new Error("test");
client.emit(road, { success: false, err: error });
```

result in:

[image: websocket google chrome]

About the server (that emit the `Error`):

- node: v12.16.1
- socket.io: "2.3.0

About the client (that receive the `Error`):

- chrome: Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- socket.io-client: ^2.3.0,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As writing here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20916142/12530707
Socket.io perform a `JSON.stringify` on the object before to send it on the socket.
As you can figure out by yourself in your console, typing `JSON.stringify(new Error("test"))` result in `{}`;

What I can advise you is to check the object class instance before to send it in order to convert it in a "valid" object yourself:

```js
if (err instanceof Error)
   err = { message: err.message, stack: err.stack };
client.emit(road, { success: false, err: err });
```